# kmsPermission Denied to insert a GCE Disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, identity-management

I am getting the below mentioned error while executing the terraform code for gcp resource notebook-runtime creation.
Basically notebook disk is not getting created due to some kms error. Which in turn is causing the notebook to be not created

Error: Error waiting to create Runtime: Error waiting for Creating Runtime: Error code 3, message: operation "projects/xxxxxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/operations/create-9a51523a-349e-4b56-b705-f6d4989ffc90" completed with error: %!w(*status.Status=&{{{} [] [] } 3 kmsPermissionDenied; [Disk][:disk-9a51523a-349e-4b56-b705-f6d4989ffc90] ; Failed to insert a GCE Disk [0xc02c4c22d0] [] 173})

on main.tf line 102, in resource "google_notebooks_runtime" "managed":
102: resource "google_notebooks_runtime" "managed" {